# .Net Core 2.0 react redux template update webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, .net-core, react-redux

I created my app with `dotnet new reactredux` (2.0) some time ago, it uses webpack 2.5.3, I'm really keeen to update to more up to date version, however there are plenty of dependecies that don't support newer versions. Is there anybody who successfully did that?

dependecies that bother me a most:

- aspnet-webpack
- aspnet-webpack-react

seems discountinued

there my full project dependencies:

```
 "devDependencies": {
"@types/history": "4.6.0",
"@types/jest": "^22.1.3",
"@types/react": "^16.3.13",
"@types/react-dom": "^16.0.4",
"@types/react-hot-loader": "3.0.3",
"@types/react-redux": "4.4.45",
"@types/react-router": "^4.0.23",
"@types/react-router-dom": "^4.2.5",
"@types/react-router-redux": "5.0.3",
"@types/webpack": "2.2.15",
"@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
"@types/fetch-mock": "^6.0.0",
"@types/enzyme": "^3.1.10",
"@types/enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.0.2",
"enzyme": "^3.3.0",
"enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
"aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
"aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
"aspnet-webpack-react": "^3.0.0",
"awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
"css-loader": "0.28.4",
"domain-task": "^3.0.3",
"event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
"extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
"file-loader": "0.11.2",
"foundation-sites": "^6.4.4-rc1",
"history": "4.6.3",
"jest": "22.4.2",
"jest-cli": "22.4.2",
"fetch-mock": "^6.0.1",
"jquery": "3.2.1",
"node-noop": "1.0.0",
"node-sass": "^4.7.2",
"react": "^16.3.2",
"react-dom": "^16.2.0",
"react-hot-loader": "3.0.0-beta.7",
"react-redux": "5.0.5",
"react-router-dom": "4.2.2",
"react-router-redux": "5.0.0-alpha.6",
"redux": "3.7.1",
"redux-thunk": "2.2.0",
"sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
"style-loader": "0.18.2",
"ts-jest": "22.0.4",
"ts-nameof": "^0.10.3",
"typescript": "2.4.1",
"url-loader": "0.5.9",
"webpack": "2.5.1",
"webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
"webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
"circular-dependency-plugin": "^4.4.0"
```

Comment: From Beowulf59000 : `I know it's not a good answer, but why not use create-react-app ? Many developers use it to start their projects and it is often updated, I think you'll not have these dependencies troubles anymore with this template.`

Comment: Well, i cannot use it now, because it is already created

Comment: Those packages are only meant to support the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices) NuGet package. In any case you are a bit hasty. Webpack 4 was released on February 2018.There's already an issue about [Webpack 4 support](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/1562) in the package, opened on March 6th and at least one [relevant PR submitted on April 10th](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/pull/1606). People are waiting for the maintainer to merge it

Comment: on the other hand, .NET Core 2.1 RTM gets released on May 30 with early bits already available [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/2.1.0-Early-Access-Downloads). I'd guess the MS maintainers were a bit busy the last couple of weeks